# Unity Android Touch Controls Not Working - 2D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have this script which i created to detect UP and DOWN swipes. All it needs to do is change the UI text..

The script is below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TouchControls : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Vector2 startPos;

    Text instruction;

    void start() {
        instruction = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    float swipeValue = 0.0f;
    void Update()
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        if (Input.touchCount > 0){
                Touch touch = Input.touches[0];
                if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began){
                    startPos = touch.position;
                }
                else if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended){

                    swipeValue = Mathf.Sign(touch.position.y - startPos.y);

                    if (swipeValue > 0){//up swipe

                        instruction.text="UP";
                    }   
                    else if (swipeValue < 0){//down swipe

                        instruction.text="DOWN";
                    }
                }
            }
        #endif
        }
    }
```

It is not working and I cannot understand why? Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution to the problem I had managed on Unity version 5.1.1

```
void Update () {

        #if UNITY_IOS || UNITY_ANDROID
        //iOS Controls (same as Android because they both deal with screen touches)
        //if the touch count on the screen is higher than 0, then we allow stuff to happen to control the player.

                if(Input.touchCount > 0){
                    foreach(Touch touch1 in Input.touches) {
                        if (touch1.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                            firstPosition = touch1.position;
                            lastPosition = touch1.position;
                        }
                        if (touch1.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
                            lastPosition = touch1.position;
                        }
                        if (touch1.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {             

                            if (firstPosition.y - lastPosition.y < -80) {
                                //Up
                            }  else {
                                //Down
                            }

                        }   

                    }

            #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, are you testing for the touch on the actual device or in the editor? The code should work on the device, but will not do so in the Editor to my knowledge. 
You will need to check for input by using 
`Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0);    //returns true if the button has been released` 
`Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);  //returns true if the button has been pressed`

 and 
`Vector3 touch = Input.mousePosition; //returns the mouse position`

 instead.

Comment: I'm testing on the actual device... :)

Comment: Then please try using instead of Touch touch = Input.touches[0]; --> Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0); 
There seems to be a weirdness about Input.touches going on that I will not be able to explain you, but GetTouch is working for me for sure, unless there is some other error in your code. Oh and also do a test for the EQUALS =  in:  if (swipeValue >= 0){  just to make sure that the if statement is triggered in case swipeValue IS 0.